# When opening a new tab with a new tab page replacement add-on, how to keep the address bar clear?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a new tab page replacement add-on for Firefox. After it's installed, when I click the new tab icon to open a new tab, the new tab opens fine, but the address bar shows a messy URL:
resource://firefox_p-at-getblog-dot-com/getblog_buttons_page/data/newtab.html

How do I make the address bar empty?

Comment: I don't know why you down voted, I fixed it, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

There are only a [few pages](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e4843f4f08a7/browser/base/content/browser.js#l161) that will have "blank" uris in the URI bar.

Now, you have a couple of options:

- Overlay/inject into `browser.xul` and just add your add-on URI to `gInitialPages`
  Or combine the about module and `gInitialPages` stuff.
- Implement an about module like @canuckistani suggests. While this will still display an URI, it will be a much nicer one. ;)
- Or, as a last resort, [`override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Chrome_Registration) `about:newTab`. This can (will?) have side-effects, however, like other add-ons still overlaying `about:newTab` which now happens to be the new page from your add-on, which might or might not work at all and/or break stuff.

Comment: I want to try the override about:newTab method. Can you elaborate on this? How do I override about:newTab? Thanks.

Comment: Since this is actually the least favorable and most error prone method of all, I decided not to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function called `setCurrentURI` on the `webNavigation`/`docShell` object. It's a funky one, I never found a real use for it. But it does exactly what you need.

```
gBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(Services.io.newURI('about:blank', null, null))
```

setting it to `about:blank` blanks it out, you can set it to any url though, it won't change the page, just the url.

so listen to page `DOMContentLoaded` of that new tab, and as soon as it loads run this code. maybe can change it even faster, like detect when the value of the input box changes.

I couldn't figure out how to make it set the url to actually read `about:newtab`, maybe someone else can help us, it seems if you set it to `about:ANYTHING` it just blanks the url bar IF `ANYTHING` is already taken by an about url, so like about:newtab, about:about blanks it. It's weird maybe someone can help us figure out how to spoof that I'm curious too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to replace that with your own custom about: protocol - here are soem docs on how to do this:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Custom_about:_URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Custom_about%3a_URLs)

Here's a real-world example of this in a fairly complex SDK-addon: https://github.com/mixedpuppy/about-awards/blob/master/lib/main.js#L171-L192